# Snake food collision detection

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-development

I am making a snake game with plain javascript. But now I have come to the food part of the game. but I just cant get it to work properly. I have an food function that generates random cords within the gamefield and then draws the food. This is already quite wonky at the first place. but then I want to detect of the snake cords and foodcords match up with a margin of 20px. but I just cant get it to word smoothly together.

Can anyone maybe help me figure out what is going wrong and how I can fix this? Thanks!

````
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let movespeedX = 2;
    let movespeedY = 0;
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    //newest cord
    let locationX = 20;
    let locationY = 20;
    //cords up to snakelength
    let cords = [
        {X: 5, Y: 5}
    ];

    let snakeLength = 5;
    
    //food location
    let foodX;
    let foodY;
    let isfood = false;

    //onload draw, move and set food
    window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(callField => {draw(); move(); food()}, 1000/60);

    //keyboard controls
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        const key = event.key.toLowerCase();
        if(key == "w" || key == "arrowup")
        {
            movespeedX = 0;
            movespeedY = -2;
        }
        if(key == "s" || key == "arrowdown")
        {
            movespeedX = 0;
            movespeedY = 2;
        }
        if(key == "a" || key == "arrowleft")
        {
            movespeedY = 0;
            movespeedX = -2;
        }
        if(key == "d" || key == "arrowright")
        {
            movespeedY = 0;
            movespeedX = 2;
        }
    });
    }

    function move()
    {
        //add movespeed to location to move all directions
        locationX += movespeedX;
        locationY += movespeedY;

        //if a wall is hit restart
        if(cords[0].X >= canvas.width || cords[0].X <= 0 || cords[0].Y >= canvas.height || cords[0].Y < 0)
        {
            restart();
        }

        //if food is hit with 20px margin (this is currently verry trippy and does not work)
        if(foodY+20 > cords[0].X && foodY+20 > cords[0].Y)
        {
            isfood = false;
            snakeLength += 5;
        }
        
        //update cords array with newest location
        cords.unshift({X: locationX, Y: locationY});
        if(cords.length > snakeLength)
        {
            delete cords[snakeLength];
        }
    }

    function draw()
    {
        //draw canvas
        drawRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,"black");
        //draw food
        drawCircle(foodX, foodY, 20, "red");
        //draw snake
        cords.forEach(element => {
            drawCircle(element.X+20,element.Y,20,"white");
        });
    }
   
    //reset to standard values
    function restart()
    {
        locationX = 20;
        locationY = 20;
        movespeedX = 0;
        movespeedY = 0;
        snakeLength = 1;
        cords = [
            {X: 0, Y: 0}
        ];
    }

    //if the is no food, generate new cords and set food to true
    function food()
    {
        if(isfood === false)
        {
            foodX = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width) + 50;
            foodY = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height) + 50;
            isfood = true;
        }
    }
   
    function drawRect(leftX, topY, width, height, color)
    {
        canvasContext.fillStyle = color;
        canvasContext.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);
    } 
    function drawCircle(leftX,topY,radius,color)
    {
        canvasContext.fillStyle = color;
        canvasContext.beginPath();
        canvasContext.arc(leftX,topY,radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        canvasContext.fill()
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use Pythagorean theorem to find the distance of two objects then for circles account the radius plus any additional buffer you may want.

So something like

```
if (distance < objects.radius + other.objects.radius) {
  return true
}
```

Here's your code

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let movespeedX = 2;
let movespeedY = 0;
var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
//newest cord
let locationX = 20;
let locationY = 20;
//cords up to snakelength
let cords = [{ X: 5, Y: 5 }];

let snakeLength = 5;

//food location
let foodX;
let foodY;
let isfood = false;

//onload draw, move and set food
window.onload = function () {
  setInterval((callField) => {
    draw();
    move();
    food();
  }, 1000 / 60);

  //keyboard controls
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    const key = event.key.toLowerCase();
    if (key == "w" || key == "arrowup") {
      movespeedX = 0;
      movespeedY = -2;
    }
    if (key == "s" || key == "arrowdown") {
      movespeedX = 0;
      movespeedY = 2;
    }
    if (key == "a" || key == "arrowleft") {
      movespeedY = 0;
      movespeedX = -2;
    }
    if (key == "d" || key == "arrowright") {
      movespeedY = 0;
      movespeedX = 2;
    }
  });
};

function move() {
  //add movespeed to location to move all directions
  locationX += movespeedX;
  locationY += movespeedY;

  //if a wall is hit restart
  if (
    cords[0].X >= canvas.width ||
    cords[0].X <= 0 ||
    cords[0].Y >= canvas.height ||
    cords[0].Y < 0
  ) {
    restart();
  }

  //if food is hit with 20px margin (this is currently verry trippy and does not work)
  let dx = foodX - cords[0].X;
  let dy = foodY - cords[0].Y;
  let dist = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
  if (dist < 60) {
    isfood = false;
    snakeLength += 5;
  }

  //update cords array with newest location
  cords.unshift({ X: locationX, Y: locationY });
  if (cords.length > snakeLength) {
    delete cords[snakeLength];
  }
}

function draw() {
  //draw canvas
  drawRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, "black");
  //draw food
  drawCircle(foodX, foodY, 20, "red");
  //draw snake
  cords.forEach((element) => {
    drawCircle(element.X + 20, element.Y, 20, "white");
  });
}

//reset to standard values
function restart() {
  locationX = 20;
  locationY = 20;
  movespeedX = 0;
  movespeedY = 0;
  snakeLength = 1;
  cords = [{ X: 0, Y: 0 }];
}

//if the is no food, generate new cords and set food to true
function food() {
  if (isfood === false) {
    foodX = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width) + 50;
    foodY = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height) + 50;
    isfood = true;
  }
}

function drawRect(leftX, topY, width, height, color) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = color;
  canvasContext.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);
}
function drawCircle(leftX, topY, radius, color) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = color;
  canvasContext.beginPath();
  canvasContext.arc(leftX, topY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  canvasContext.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```